# Create a Shapefile from SQL dump file

Tags: postgis, postgresql, convert, mapserver, pgsql2shp

I am trying to map data by querying a table called xyz. I need to show the the_geom data on the map.

I have below query in my MapServer .map file:

```
DATA "the_geom from xyz using unique id using SRID=xxxx"
```

I need to generate a shapefile in order to get the data. I have

```
SHAPEPATH "../data" defined in my .map file.
```

But I am not sure command I should write for generating shapefile for above query, I tried doing

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pgsql2shp -f /home/name/public_html/proj/data/xyz -h xxx.xxx.xx.xx -u username -P passwrd dbname "select the_geom from xyz"
```

This generated some files which I have it in by data folder. But I see blank page on my webpage.

Please correct me!

Comment: You can validate the shapefile with other tools, like QGIS. But why not [directly serve the data from postgis](http://mapserver.org/input/vector/postgis.html)?

Comment: Also try [shp2img](http://mapserver.org/utilities/shp2img.html) to try and generate output for MapServer.

Comment: or if you really need a Shapefile than you should also consider `ogr2ogr`, more examples [here](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can render your data from PostgreSQL directly. Documentation [here](http://mapserver.org/input/vector/postgis.html).

PostgreSQL layer example:

```
LAYER
  NAME "province"
  STATUS ON
  TYPE POLYGON
  CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
  CONNECTION "host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=xyz user=postgres password=postgres"
  DATA "the_geom from xyz"
  CLASS
    STYLE
      COLOR 128 128 128
      ANTIALIAS true
    END
  END
END
```

2. You can export data from PostgreSql to shapefile or other format use psql2shp

Convert from postgres like this:

```
$ pgsql2shp -f <path to output shapefile> -h <hostname> -u <username> -P <password> databasename "<query>"
```

For example (creates xyz.shp in current directory):

```
$ pgsql2shp -f xyz -h 127.0.0.1 -u postgres -P password postgres "SELECT name, the_geom FROM xyz"

Initializing... 
Done (postgis major version: 2).
Output shape: Polygon
Dumping: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [23 rows].
```

And create Mapserver layer (documentation [here](http://mapserver.org/input/vector/ogr.html)) Note what you must change map `EXTENT` value, use the **ogrinfo** utility `ogrinfo -al -so xyz.shp` read more [here](http://mapserver.org/tutorial/example1-1.html#map-object).

Example mapfile:

```
MAP
  IMAGETYPE      GIF
  EXTENT         23.49 59.3 23.60 59.68
  SIZE           400 400
  SHAPEPATH      "/home/name/public_html/proj/data/"
  IMAGECOLOR     255 255 255

  LAYER
    NAME         veget
    DATA         Poltava10_Vegetation_region
    STATUS       ON
    TYPE         POLYGON
    CLASS
      STYLE
        COLOR    25 210 12
      END
    END
  END
END
```